# "cutil64D.dll is missing from your computer" error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, configuration, cuda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing cutil debug library: Cannot open file cutil32D.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944362/missing-cutil-debug-library-cannot-open-file-cutil32d-lib)

I installed **CUDA Toolkit 4.0.17 (64-bit)** and **CUDA SDK 4.0.19 (64-bit)** and using **Visual Studio 2008**. When I create a new `CUDA Project in VS` and run in it, debug/release/Win32/x64 (any config),  I get the same error. I am using a workstation from a remote desktop that has Windows 7 (64-bit) and have 3 Graphics Cards installed:

```
 1. NVIDIA Quadro FX 3800 and 
 2. NVIDIA Tesla C2050/2070
 3. NVIDIA Tesla C2050/2070.
```

**My C:\Windows\System32 has the following present:**

```
1. cublas64_31_9.dll
2. cudart64_31_9.dll
```

In my VS project I have the following config for "All Configurations":

```
 1. Additional Library Directories - "$(CUDA_LIB_PATH)";"$(NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT)\C\common\lib\x64"
 2. Additional Dependencies - cudart.lib cutil64D.lib
```

And in VS "Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories" I have the following settings:

```
1. Exec files - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\bin
 2. Include files - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include
 3. Lib files - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\lib\x64
```

Can you please tell what am I doing wrong, or what do I need to correct?

From previous posts it seems Tesla should work on RDP but bandwidthTest.exe shows no CUDA-capable device...

Comment: Did you install the 32 bit or 64 bit version?

Comment: 64 bit versions of everything. Windows, Toolkit and SDK.

Comment: Is the error really "cuda64D.dll" is missing or is it "cutil64D.dll" is missing?

Comment: Tesla only works in RDP mode if the Tesla cards are [placed in TCC mode](http://choorucode.com/2011/08/12/cuda-on-tesla-over-remote-desktop/).  Are your Tesla cards in TCC mode?

Comment: @talonmies: Ah sorry I updated the question

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Let me try that link...

Comment: @user1961040: Right, so that error is because you haven't compiled the cutil library. It is shipped in source form with the SDK, and requires compilation before you can use it. If you read and follow the instruction that comes with the SDK for building the examples, the problem will go away.

Comment: my statement about TCC mode was intended to address the observation that bandwidthTest reports no CUDA devices, and I presume it will also be necessary once the cutil issue gets fixed.

Comment: So I fixed the problem by copying 'cutil64.lib', 'cutil64D.lib', 'cutil64.dll', 'cutil64D.dll' in the project folder and where the project .exe file is created. Although the path to these files was already present in Visual Studio configuration. Also noticed, that the environment variable used in VS and Windows Advanced Settings have a bit different names: `NVSDKCUDA_ROOT` and `NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT`, which is really weird. Now I just have both set and pointing to the same location: `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2`